# EJB local and remote in the same project

Tags: java, ejb

I have an application with DAO, Service, Web.

I want to use EJB local and remote to access my service.

I created an interface to define the methods and an interface with `@Local` and another with `@Remote`, according below.

Interface with methods:

```
public interface OrigemArquivoClient extends BasicCrudFacade<OrigemArquivo, OrigemArquivoSearch, Integer>   {

     public void doSomething();
}
```

Interface `@Local`

```
@Local 
public interface OrigemArquivoClientLocal extends BasicCrudFacade<OrigemArquivo, OrigemArquivoSearch, Integer>, OrigemArquivoClient {

}
```

Interface `@Remote`

```
@Remote
public interface OrigemArquivoClientRemote extends BasicCrudFacade<OrigemArquivo, OrigemArquivoSearch, Integer>, OrigemArquivoClient {
}
```

To inject the local EJB I am using like bellow and is working.

```
@EJB(beanName="OrigemArquivoServiceBean")
private OrigemArquivoClientLocal service;
```

And to remote I am trying to lookup:

```
bean = ctx.lookup("java:global/" + ear + "/" + projeto + "/" + ejb);
```

Host that is using to lookup is java:`global.EDIEAR.EDIWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.OrigemArquivoServiceBean`. However, in the weblogic exists "`!br`" at the end of **jndi**, and when I try to lookup with it ,`java:global.EDIEAR.EDIWeb-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.OrigemArquivoServiceBean!br` I have the result bellow, that inst my remote EJB, but a weblogic instance of anything.

[Click to image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QICPc.png)

Answer (score 0):

Try somthing like this:

```
try {
    Context ctx = new InitialContext();
    MyEJBLocal myEjb = (MyEJBLocal) ctx.lookup("java:comp/env/jndiName"); // suppose br???
} catch (NamingException e) {
    throw new EJBException(e);
}
```